# C++: Pascal's Triangle

Tags: c++

I am struggling on how to interpret and/or relate between *comb(i, j)* to *long comb(int n, int k)*. May you please explain to me how the for loop of the *long comb(int n, int k)* works? Thank you very much.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

long comb(int, int);

int main()
{
 int m;
 cout << "Type a number and then press ENTER: ";
 cin >> m;

 for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
 {
  for(int j = 1; j < (m - i); j++)
  {
   cout << setw(2) << "";
  }
  for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
  {
   cout << setw(4) << comb(i, j);
  }
 cout << endl;
 }
}

long comb(int n, int k)
{
 if (n < 0 || k < 0 || n < k)
 {
  return 0;
 }
 long c= 1;
 for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++, n--)
 {
  c = c*(n/i);
 }
 return c;
}
```

Edit: Thank Yunnosch for the correction.

Comment: What's the issue? `comb(i, j)` means you are passing `n = i` and `k = j` to the function. Your `comb` function simply calculates the value of `nCk`.

Comment: is it syntax (two loop counters) or logic you do not understand? For logic you should take pen and paper to draw a triangle then use a debugger to step through the code. For syntax you could clarify what exactly is confusing you

Comment: _how the for loop of the long comb(int n, int k) works_ : it basically multiplies `(n/i)` to `c` in each iteration, decreasing `n` and increasing `i` after each iteration. You should try writing it down yourself you'll get its nothing but a way to calculate the value of binomial coefficient, `nCk`.

Comment: Please double check, this seems very much like a typo `long comb(int, int)`, it should be `long comb(int, int);` note the semicolon. With that I doubt that you can compile and I do not want to discuss the errors/warnings you get for a typo.

Comment: So for the first iteration of the `long comb(int n, int k)`, the value of n is equal to 0 and then j is equal to 1? What is the initial value of k then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop in the `long comb(int n, int k)` is calculating the Binomial Coefficients using the [Multiplicative Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula).

You could also write that for loop like below (which looks more like the multiplicative formula):

```cpp
for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
    c = c * ((n - i + 1) / i); 
}
```

The

```
long comb(int, int);
```

before `int main()` is the [*declaration*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm#:%7E:text=A%20function%20declaration%20tells%20the,that%20your%20program%20can%20call.) of the `long comb(int n, int k)` function. You have to do it, so that the code compiles. Another way would be to *define* the `long comb(int n, int k)` function completely before `main()` instead of after it. You should understand the difference between declaration and definition in C++.

By the way, your code seems to have a bug, and does not print the correct Pascal triangle.

Comment: I already corrected the code. Thanks for responding.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please upvote it and mark it as accepted :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

These are the meanings of the different occurrences of `comb()` in your code.

```
long comb(int, int);
```

This means "Dear compiler. Later on I will provide code for a function of this name with these parameter types. Please accept that I call it before you have seen the code."
It is called a "prototype".

```
cout << setw(4) << comb(i, j);
```

Means "Dear compiler, remember the function I told you about but have not shown you the code for? Call it here please, as part of making output; the code is below somewhere."

```
long comb(int n, int k)
{
/* ... */
}
```

Means "Dear compiler, with the prototype above I promised to provide code for a function of this name and parameters. I even asked you to call it from other code. Here I finally provide the code for it. Please use this code for the execution of the call from main()."
(Some of this last part actually addresses more the linker than the compiler, but I think that level of detail is out of scope here.)

Answer (score 1):

I have the impression that you don't understand how to learn how to program:
An experienced programmer looks at a piece of code and understands what it means, but for a starting programmer most of the times this does not work: you need to try the piece of code, debug it, try to understand it and mostly, **try it out**.

Let's have a look at `comb(n,k)`: apparently n must be larger than k, so let's have a look at what happens for the values n=8 and k=3:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++, n--)
 {
  c = c*(n/i);
 }
```

What happens with i and c?

```
   i      k      n      c
   1      3      8      1*8/1
   2      3      7      1*8/1*7/2
   3      3      6      1*8/1*7/2*6/3
```

So, at the end: c becomes `8*7*6/(1*2*3)`.

I admit: two variables get changed during the loop (`i++` and `n--`), which is confusing indeed, but by trying out you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: from my experience it can take days to weeks to understand a piece of code. How easy it is to understand code does not depend that much on the skills of the reader, but more on the skills of who wrote the code. Anyhow, if someone claims to understand every detail of some non-trivial code without trying, testing and debugging then I wouldnt believe them that they are experienced

Comment: I just started studying C++.Thank you for the replies and sound advice. I truly appreciate it.